# How to adjust size and frequency of procedural texture independently

Tags: texturing

I'm trying to create a procedural texture based material in which I can get a transition from a completely black area to a completely white one by decreasing the size of the black parts of the texture (I make use of Color Ramp to get only pure black and pure white areas).

For example, I've tried to set the size of the texture elements by using the Factor socket of a Gradient Texture as input for the Scale socket of a Wave Texture.

I get the expected result of waves that decrease their size but I get their frequency to increase as well, so the final effect is of a overall constant density, instead I'm trying to get a transition from a high density to a low density areas.
Same results using the other procedural textures (Noise, Voronoi, Musgrave, ...).

It looks as if you increase the distance between your point of view and the object so you see waves or spots smaller but closer to each other at the same time.

I'm wondering how to control Size and/or Frequency separately. 
Can you please help me?

As suggested here is an image to better explain my question.

[image: As suggested here are an image to better explain my question.]

Thank you.
Antonio

Comment: i think adding images would help to get the picture

Comment: See this: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/122740/how-to-make-multiple-strips-for-a-wipe-with-animation-nodes

Answer (score 16, accepted):

this node setup will produce the texture you want where you control the frequencies  by the value of *Freq* and the size by the gradient ( you can pass it through a ColorRamp for more control ) :

[image]

the result :

[image]

Here is a node setup to achieve a similar result  :

[image]

the result texture :

[image]

Comment: Great solutions, especially the second one because I can easily apply it to other Blender procedural texture as well.
Thank you so much. +1