# How to make multiple strips for a wipe with Animation Nodes?

Tags: animation-nodes

This is my original strip in Moho Pro. 
[image]

When I group strips while moving each a little to the left and delaying them each by a second or two, this is what I get. Now how do I reproduce that with Animation Nodes? 
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an inverse *Delay Falloff* to offset matrices by translating and scaling them along the x axis:

[image: Node Tree]

Comment: This is brilliant. Great mant thanks. I wish I have your brain for nodes.